# Including React component in static html page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to include a basic react component into an html page. The react app is created with `create-react-app`

```
mkdir my_html_app
cd my_html_app
npx create-react-app my_react_app
```

I then made the app a component by editing `my_html_app/my_react_app/src/App.js`

```
// App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        This is my react component
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Then build the app

```
npm run build
```

Then created `index.html` in `my_html_app`

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/my_react_app/build/static/js/main.d286e0ff.chunk.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
</head>
<body>
    My html app. Expecting to see react component here:
    <div id="my_app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var el = React.createElement(App);
        ReactDOM.render(el, document.getElementById("my_app"))
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

From there i can an error `(index):12 Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined`

What am i doing wrong here? I assume im building wrong. What are the steps of properly using that build file?

Comment: Why are you writing the HTML document from scratch instead of using the one generated by `npm run build`?

Comment: This is going to be a php app that uses this react component. Just trying to start with a basic html to test out how the integration is going to work

Comment: `npm run build` generates that basic HTML which, for example, **doesn't** load React from a CDN because it is compiled in already.

Comment: You should camelCase your file names (that's a common practice). If you accidentally use "app" instead of "App" (since your file uses a ```A``` instead of ```a```), window machines running the code would have no problems with casing, however, linux machines would crash on run time because it wouldn't know how to find the file. Just a heads up!

Comment: @JasonBellomy — Naming the file after the default export is also a common practise, and react components have to start with a capital letter, so `App` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

App is not defined in your index.html. What you can do is create an index.js file, export your App file, and then in your html file, you can use require.js to pull your index and access the app from there (require.js will need to be installed in your node modules):

index.js file in the src folder of your application (my_html_app/my_react_app/src/index.js)

```
export App from "./App";
```

Then update your html file like so:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/my_react_app/build/static/js/main.d286e0ff.chunk.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
</head>
<body>
    My html app. Expecting to see react component here:
    <div id="my_app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require([string path to your index file], function(Main) {
            var el = React.createElement(Main.App);
            ReactDOM.render(el, document.getElementById("my_app"))
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. Have you tested this locally?

Comment: I don't have your files, nor do I have your file structure, so I can't really test it locally. My code above is more of an example of how you can do it. If you are using require, then this will work. If you are not using require, then you need to use some kind of build tool (require, babel, etc...) to have it build your files and components to be injected into your html page.

Comment: i see, ya im pretty much starting from scratch at that mkdir, just an empty project.